# How to get any specific column data from a table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table into which data is fetched from database. In the same table I have two buttons. By pressing either button I want to get all specific column data. I tried several ways. See code below.

[image: table pic]

**HTML & PHP that produce above table:**

```
    <table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th style="width:20%;">Vendor Picture Path</th>
  <th style="width:20%;">Vendor Heading</th>
  <th style="width:20%;">Vendor Adding Date</th>
  <th style="width:20%;">Vendor Body</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">Add A Course</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">Add A Batch</th>
</tr>
<?php

mysql_connect("hist", "user", "pass")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
    mysql_select_db("name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "query";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         echo '<tr>
         <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["pic_path"].'</div></td>             
         <td><div onclick="getval(this)" class="cventablehead" id="ventablehead" style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll; cursor: pointer; color:red;">'.$row["heading"].'</div></td>
         <td>'.$row["adding_date"].'</td>
         <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["body"].'</div></td>
         <td><button onclick="addcourse(this)">Add</button></td>
         <td><button onclick="addbatch(this)">Add</button></td>
         </tr>';
    }
?>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:** *Each alert is a different way I tried without success*

```
  function addcourse(obj)
  {
    alert(obj.querySelector('#ventablehead').innerHTML);
    alert(obj.getElementsByClassName("cventablehead").innerHTML);
    alert(obj.getElementsByClassName("cventablehead")[0].innerHTML);
  }
```

Comment: How could that possibly work? You're creating *multiple* elements with the *same* id in your while loop, which is a no-no. Multiple elements can have the same class, but not the same id. At least fix that.  **@Filipe_Duarte's** answer below looks like it's on the right track. You should upvote any answers you like and click the checkmark (√) next to the one that solves your problem to give them credit for helping.

Comment: Also, why fight with JavaScript to manipulate the DOM? Why not use jQuery? It's so much more convenient to write and use and so much more concise and easily readable in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a specific id for each HTML element:

```
mysql_connect("hist", "user", "pass")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
mysql_select_db("name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "query";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i = 0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     echo '<tr>
     <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["pic_path"].'</div></td>             
     <td><div onclick="getval(this)" class="cventablehead" id="ventablehead_'.$i'" style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll; cursor: pointer; color:red;">'.$row["heading"].'</div></td>
     <td>'.$row["adding_date"].'</td>
     <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["body"].'</div></td>
     <td><button onclick="addcourse('.$i.')">Add</button></td>
     <td><button onclick="addbatch(this)">Add</button></td>
     </tr>';
     $i++;
}
?>
  </table>
</div>


function addcourse(index) {
    alert(document.getElementById('#ventablehead_'+index).innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "cell-content" attribute to your button to specify the column you want to get data from:

```
<td><button type="button" class="addcourse" cell-content="1">Add</td>
```

And attach a listener to your buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('addcourse');

    var findAncestor = function (el, sel) {
        while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
        return el;
    };

    var getCellContent = function (row, cellIndex) {
        return row.cells[cellIndex].firstChild.innerHTML;
    };

    var onClick = function() {
        // Find <tr> ancestor of the clicked button
        var row = findAncestor(this, 'tr');

        var data = getCellContent(row, this.getAttribute('cell-content'));

        console.log(data);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks,but its show something like <div onclick="getval(this)" style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll; cursor: pointer; color:red;">CISCO</div>.how can i get only innerhtml